# Changing Cell colour using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors

Hi I am very new to VBA in excel and very rusty writing code in general.
I have written code so that if I select cell A2 then Cells A5 and G5 turn yellow. Now I want to keep that selection but also turn for example G5 purple still having only selected A2. If this possible? Can you show me how? Thank you!

Current code:

```
Select.Case Target.Adress
Case "$A$2" 
    .Range (A2,A5,G5).Interior.Color =RGB (255, 255, 0)
```

Comment: No. You would have to do it in two separate steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change color for each cell.

```
Select Case Target.Adress
Case "$A$2"
   .Range("A2,A5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
   .Range("G5").Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it would be a simple fix but it just wasn’t coming to me! works perfectly and helps me immensely!